# Pass current user to factory in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter

So I am working on twitter integration in my app now that i got authentication to work well. 
I am using a .factory to do my twitter work and it works great. the problem is I want to change the screen name it checks based on what user profile is currently open. 
like so:

```
get('/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=<users twitter>&count=1'
```

this would be easy if I could use $scope in my factory, but every time I try and implement it, stuff breaks.

```
angular.module('myApp.service', []).factory('twitterService', function($q) {

var authorizationResult = false;
return {
    initialize : function() {
        //initialize OAuth.io with public key of the application
        OAuth.initialize('SYd6rvZZTLQT-oJxWOeNctFuUyA', {
            cache : true
        });
//try to create an authorization result when the page loads,
//this means a returning user won't have to click the twitter button again
        authorizationResult = OAuth.create('twitter');
    },
    isReady : function() {
        return (authorizationResult);
    },
    connectTwitter : function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        OAuth.popup('twitter', {
            cache : true
        }, function(error, result) {
//cache means to execute the callback if the tokens are already present
            if (!error) {
                authorizationResult = result;
                deferred.resolve();
            } else {
                //do something if there's an error
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    },
    clearCache : function() {
        OAuth.clearCache('twitter');
        authorizationResult = false;
    },
    getLatestTweets : function() {
        //create a deferred object using $q service
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = authorizationResult.get('/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=cnn&count=1').done(function(data)  {//https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/home_timeline
            //when the data is retrieved resolved the deferred object
            deferred.resolve(data)
        });
        //return the promise of the deferred object
        return deferred.promise;
        }
    }

});
```

if I could use something like

```
.factory('twitterService', ['$scope', function ($q, $scope) {
```

that would work.

--------------Edit----------

So now I know I shouldnt use $scope in my factory, and instead I want to do all the authentication in the factory and pass that to the controller.
Here is my existing controller:

```
.controller('TwitterController', function($scope, $q, twitterService) {

    $scope.tweets; //array of tweets

    twitterService.initialize();
    // console.log("auth for twitter" +authorizationResult);
    //using the OAuth authorization result get the latest 20 tweets from twitter for the user
    $scope.refreshTimeline = function() {
        twitterService.getLatestTweets().then(function(data) {
            $scope.tweets = data;
        });
    }
    //when the user clicks the connect twitter button, the popup authorization window opens
    $scope.connectButton = function() {
        twitterService.connectTwitter().then(function() {
            if (twitterService.isReady()) {
                //if the authorization is successful, hide the connect button and display the tweets
                $('#connectButton').fadeOut(function(){
                    $('#getTimelineButton, #signOut').fadeIn();
                    $scope.refreshTimeline();
                });
            }
        });
    }
    //sign out clears the OAuth cache, the user will have to reauthenticate when returning
    $scope.signOut = function() {
        twitterService.clearCache();
        $scope.tweets.length = 0;
        $('#getTimelineButton, #signOut').fadeOut(function(){
            $('#connectButton').fadeIn();
        });
    }

    //if the user is a returning user, hide the sign in button and display the tweets
    if (twitterService.isReady()) {
        $('#connectButton').hide();
        $('#getTimelineButton, #signOut').show();
        $scope.refreshTimeline();
    }

})
```

So I should send the authentication data to my controller and have the controller do the actual Get api request. Maybe its because its really early for me but I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how I would do this.

Comment: `.factory('twitterService', ['$scope', function ($q, $scope) {` is wrong, should be `.factory('twitterService', ['$q', '$scope', function ($q, $scope) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not pass any scope to your factory. The factory should manage the data (e.g. authenticate, fetch username etc).

A controller should//could use the data to update the view.

Your implementation could look like this:

```
/* The SERVICE */
app.factory('authService', function () {
    var currentUser = 'Guest';
    return {
        ...
        authenticate: function (...) {
            ...
            currentUser = theUserIGotFromTwitter;
        },
        getCurrentUser: function () {
            return currentUser;
        }
    };
});

/* The CONTROLLER */
app.controller('someCtrl', function ($scope, authService) {
    $scope.getUser = authService.getCurrentUser;
    ...
});

<!-- The VIEW -->
<span>{{getUser()}}</span>
```

---

<sub>**Note:**

Based on your implementation and requirements, there might be more efficient ways to achieve this.

E.g. if you know that the controller will be responsible for authenticating the user and that it want change by some other part of the page, you could do something similar to the following:</sub>

```
/* The CONTROLLER */
app.controller('someCtrl', function ($scope, authService) {
    authService.authenticate(...).then(function (...) {
        ...
        $scope.user = authService.getCurrentUser();
    });
    ...
});

<!-- The VIEW -->
<span>{{user}}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, after reading other things I realized $scope shouldn't be used in the factory. So I was working on taking the "getLatestTweets" part and using that in the controller since I can then grab the user from my existing $scope. would that be a better approach than what you suggested?

Comment: @DualPandas: Sorry, for the late response. I don't quite get what you mean. But I don't think you should get anything off the service if it is related to fetching data from anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

So I have it working so that whenever I go to a individual persons details page it will display there last tweet. 
not the most elegant way, but it works!

```
    getLatestTweets : function() {
        //create a deferred object using $q service
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        console.log("working?"+ $rootScope.twitterUse);

        var promise = authorizationResult.get('/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='+$rootScope.twitterUse+'&count=1')
        .done(function(data) {  
            //when the data is retrieved resolved the deferred object
            deferred.resolve(data)
            console.log("data"+data);
        });
        //return the promise of the deferred object
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

which pulls twitterUse from the controller.

The big problem I forsee having is that if I want to do a list view of all the users with the most recent tweet for each this wont work. 
If anyone wants to help with that I would appreciate it.